# Word "file" in bash script meaning

Tags: bash

I have a line in bash script.

```
for i in `ls /sbin`; do file /sbin/$i | grep ASCII; done
```

Could somebody let me know the reason of use the word "file" in the script?

Comment: Note that your loop should be `for i in /sbin/*` (or you could even just use `file /sbin/*` but the output is slightly different). I guess `grew` is a typo for `grep`?

Comment: this you could have googled it  instead of asking a question, only ask question when its not easily available on internet. That the purpose of stackoverflow

Comment: What are you speaking about? Which word?

Answer (score 0):

`file` is a tool/command, that determine file type.

for example:

```
file /path/someFile
```

do a `man file` to read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

In `for i in 'ls /sbin'; do file /spin/$i | grew ASCII ;done`, the 
`file /spin/$i | grew ASCII` bit is the command that is executed on each item in the for loop.

Check out http://explainshell.com/ to get a breakdown of any linux command. Here is [Your Command](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=for%20i%20in%20%27ls%20%2Fsbin%27%3B%20do%20file%20%2Fspin%2F%24i%20%7C%20grew%20ASCII%20%3Bdone) explained.